# Switching a UIPicker for a keybaord

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uipicker

I have researched this, but found only how to switch a keyboard for a keyboard. Right now I have a UIPicker and that appears when a textfield is tapped. In the Picker their are three options, and the third is custom. What I want to happen is when custom is selected the UIPicker is replaced with a keyboard. Im guessing this would be done with the `if (select == 2) { }` method. I don't need a whole bunch of code, just the method for replacing the Picker. Also I would want to make a toolBar with a back button to get back to the picker. I currently have a toolbar with a doneButton to release the picker, but I would need to make a button appear when the keyboard appears and the button be able to switch the keyboard back to my Picker.

So far my picker, toolabr and textfield are :

```
...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"...",@"...",@"Custom", nil];
    self.PickerData = array;

...

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];

...

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(releasePicker)];


    Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Picker.delegate = self;
    doneButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, doneButton] animated:YES];
    self.habitField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.habitField setEnabled: YES];

    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];

}
- (void)releasePicker {
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
}

...

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [PickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.PickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {

        ...
    }
    if (select == 1) {

        ...
    }
    if (select == 2) {

        ...

    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (select == 2) {
      [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
      [self.habitField setInputView:nil];
      [self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This is basically hiding the UIPickerView then removing it and then popping up the keyboard.

If you want the UIPicker buck up use this code:

```
[self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
[self.habitField setInputView:PickerData];
[self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: how can I make the button bring the picker back?